# c# compiler error with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdRelativeHorizontalPosition;

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, shapes, enumerated-types

I have the below code which is for modifying a textframe in a word document at runtime.

This is in a .NET Windows Forms app.

```
var oShapes = oWord.ActiveDocument.Shapes; 
var titleShape = oShapes["Title"];

var myWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

titleShape.Height = myWord.InchesToPoints(1.75F);
titleShape.Width = myWord.InchesToPoints(0.45F);
titleShape.RelativeHorizontalPosition = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdRelativeHorizontalPosition;
titleShape.RelativeVerticalPosition =  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdRelativeVerticalPosition();
titleShape.Left = 4.35F;
titleShape.Top = 17.5F;
titleShape.TextFrame.WordWrap = 0;
titleShape.LockAnchor = 1;

var sTitle =string.Empty;

titleShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = DocumentType; // sTitle;
titleShape.TextFrame.AutoSize=-1;
```

Unfortunately I must have got it wrong because **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdRelativeHorizontalPosition;** is showing as an error in VS 2010 (and also on the line below.

What is the correct way to use word enumerated constants like that in c# through Office Interop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, I was calling the enumeration name, rather than the enumerated constant.

So `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdRelativeHorizontalPosition`

should be

`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdRelativeHorizontalPosition.wdRelativeHorizontalPositionPage;`

(plus I was using brackets thinking that was the problem)

Answer (score 1):

remove the parentheses:

```
titleShape.RelativeVerticalPosition =  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdRelativeVerticalPosition;
```

you also don't say what the compilation error is.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are calling the property as if it was a method. Remove the paranthesis at the end and you should be done.

```
titleShape.RelativeVerticalPosition =  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdRelativeVerticalPosition;
```

Hope this helps.